# NameError: name "user_choice1" is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am trying out a simple program and keep getting this particular error:

```
line 34, in <module>
user_choice1 == input("Do you want to exit or continue searching?")
NameError: name 'user_choice1' is not defined
```

Here is the piece of code that is causing the error:

```
while True:
choice = input("Do you want to add items?")
if choice == "y":
    add_items()
    more = input("Do you want to add more items?")
    if more == "y":
        add_items()
    else:
        while True:
            user_choice = input("Adding items finished. Do you want to search items or exit?")
            if user_choice == "search":
                search_item()
                while True:
                    user_choice1 == input("Do you want to exit or continue searching?")
                    if user_choice1 == "continue":
                        search_item()
                        continue 
                    elif user_choice1 == "exit":
                        sys.exit()
                    else:
                        break                
            elif user_choice == "exit":
                sys.exit
            else:
                continue


elif choice == "n":
    search_item()
    while True:
        user_choice2 = input("Searching finished. Do you want to continue or exit?")
        if user_choice2 == "continue":
            break
            continue
        elif user_choice2 == "exit":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            continue

elif choice == "exit":
    sys.exit()

else:
    print("Invalid Choice")
```

What is causing this error? I am using Python 3.5.2.
Also, is there a better way to write this code as in, is there a way to optimize this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, using a double-equal, `==`, is a logical test of equality.  Using a single-equal, `=` is an assignment.

So what you're doing is telling Python to check whether `user_choice1` is equal to the `input` statement.  It's rightly telling you that you haven't defined that variable yet.

```
x = 4 #assigns the value 4 to x
y = 4 #assigns the value 4 to y
x == y #returns True
x == 7 #returns False
```

It looks like you repeated this error in several places, so go back and switch to a single equal for all of them.

Comment: I cannot realize I missed this. I feel so dumb. Thanks for the help brother. I guess I am gonna need some sleep :)

Comment: I know what you mean, but it'd be more accurate to say that your telling Python to check whether `user_choice1` is equal to the value returned by the `input` function. BTW, we don't usually bother writing full answers to typo questions because they're unlikely to help future readers with a similar problem: they're unlikely to find this question by Googling.